# Variation of MPI_Type_indexed

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Is there a variation of MPI_Type_index where I can specify an array of block counts too?
I need to be able to send different number of blocks at different offsets. But MPI_Type_indexed only allows one to specify a noncontiguous data layout where displacements between successive blocks need not be equal. The number of blocks is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, but struck still requires a fixed count for blocks, and I don't have a fixed number of blocks. That's the problem.

Comment: Actually, what I'm really trying to accomplish is to send different number non-contiguous elements of an array to different processors, and MPI_Type_indexed seems to be a tool to do so, but it still doesn't solve the entire problem...

Comment: An MPI datatype describes a single memory layout of data; a single memory layout necessarily only has one number of blocks.